# Delegate method, how to write it without delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

Oke,

I have a delegate method and a filter where I pass the delegate. Then in the Main I return the method.

But my question is: how to write this stuff without delegate?

This is what I have:

```
 public class ProcessData
    {
        public Int32 Id;
        public Int64 Memory;
        public String Name;
    }



    delegate bool Predicate<T>(T obj);


    class Program
    {



        static void DisplayProcesses(Predicate<Process> match)
        {
            var processes = new List<ProcessData>();
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (match(process))
                {
                    processes.Add(new ProcessData
                    {
                        Id = process.Id,
                        Name = process.ProcessName,
                        Memory = process.WorkingSet64
                    });
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static Boolean Filter(Process proces)
        {

            return proces.WorkingSet64 >= 20 * 1021 * 1021;

        }
}
```

//The main method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            DisplayProcesses(Filter);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Use `Func<Process, bool>`

Comment: @CodingYoshi func is still a delegate !

Comment: @brahim yes under the hood it is but I thought the OP doesnt want to use *delegate* explicitly. Not clear about question hence i wrote comment.

Comment: What do you mean with OP?

Comment: Why do you want to do it without a delegate?

Comment: Just for understanding. I experiment a lot with code. To figure out how things work with or without some specific things. Is that strange? I don't think so. I don't know who has given this post not plus. but it is said to see that.

Comment: So what do you mean with OP?

Comment: Ok thats fine if you are experimenting. I was curious why. *OP* means *Original Poster* so it means you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write the code without a delegate just take the predicate out of filter

```
proces.WorkingSet64 >= 20 * 1021 * 1021;
```

and delete the parameter from the method

here how

```
static void DisplayProcesses()
        {
            var processes = new List<ProcessData>();
            foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
            {
                if (process.WorkingSet64 >= 20 * 1021 * 1021;)
                {
                    processes.Add(new ProcessData
                    {
                        Id = process.Id,
                        Name = process.ProcessName,
                        Memory = process.WorkingSet64
                    });
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Comment: This is a poor solution and it is no longer as flexible as what the OP has.

Comment: @CodingYoshi the OP is trying to avoid delegate read the question please